# Trigger <select> click onClick of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I'm wanting to open a `<select>` when clicking on it's parent `.select` class.

https://jsfiddle.net/6o31gfwa/ - if you click the orange block you will see that the select opens, but then clicking on an option it doesn't close the select. How may I fix this?

```
<label class="select">
    <select>
        <option>Body Fat</option>
        <option>Height</option>
        <option>Jean Size</option>
        <option>Chest</option>
        <optio>Pulse</option>
    </select>
</label>

$('body')
    .on('click', '.select', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var i = $('.select').index($(this)),
            e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');

        e.initMouseEvent('mousedown');
        $('select')[i].dispatchEvent(e);

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, right. The previous answer will not work. You can try this instead:

```
$('select.class-of-select').val(the_same_select_val).change();
```

Comment: No. That will not work. You cannot trigger a select this way. See: https://jsfiddle.net/n4b3a4w1/

Comment: @ditto Updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: I want to open the select, and then allow the user to change it's value by clicking an option.

Comment: You've incorrectly marked this as a duplicate. My question is nothing a like to the one you've linked to. Stop thinking my question is asking how to change a select value, it isnt! I'm asking how to trigger open a select from clicking another element.

Comment: @ditto Sorry then. Reopened.